# Combine two DPDT relays to make a 4PDT relay

Tags: relay, dpdt

I'm trying to come up with a replacement for the obsolete OMRON G6A-434P 4PDT relay for a replacement PCB I'm building.  I've got a bunch of OMRON G5V DPDT relays and I'm thinking wiring two of these up together with the coil polarities matched, it should work...right?  I've looked all over Google trying to find an example circuit, but I cannot find anything.  I was hoping you guys could help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two DPDT, with the coils in parallel or series, will function similarly to a single 4PDT. Just like 2 SPDT switches or relays will act like a single DPDT.

All you need to do is confirm the NO and NC pin out of your 4PDT and wire it the same way. And trigger the relay coils at the same time.

Series Coils, Double the voltage for the same current draw/coil response. Parallel Coils, Double the current draw for the same voltage.

There is nothing specifically complex about a 4PDT setup.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWeVJw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that's what i thought. I originally designed a PCB so the coils were in parallel. As with most circuits in parallel, would this also halve the current, or would it not make a difference?

Comment: @Alex I updated it. And no, with the coils in parallel, at the same voltage, you are looking at twice the current draw. Only way to avoid changes in voltage or current, would be to get relays that need half the current as the original. Then two in parallel would be the same current as the original.

Comment: @ Passerby Ah, good call on the diodes. I dont have those in my current design. I'll update it with a diode between the relays.

Comment: Not sure if the parallel relays require one or two but i doubt it hurts.